# Согласные звуки. Мягкие и твердые

Tags: фонетика

Будет ли звук "ж" мягким при транскрибации имени собственного "Жюль"?

Answer (score 2):

В ***"Словаре имён собственных"*** на Грамоте.ру рекомендовано мягкое произношение:

> [**ЖЮЛЬ**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B6%D1%8E%D0%BB%D1%8C), -я (**не *жу***) (франц. м. имя)

В транскрипции мягкость согласных показывается значком апострофа [']:

[ж'у]ль.

Ан нет, я неправ... Круглые скобки в этом словаре говорят только о написании.

Посмотрел ***"Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала XXI века: нормы и её варианты"*** (М., 2012), созданный в Институте русского языка им. В.В. Виноградова Российской академии наук.

Из этого словаря:

> В некоторых иноязычных собственных именах после ***ж, ш*** пишутся
>   буквы ***ю, я*** и возможно произношение мягких [ш'], [ж'], например:
>
> ***Жюль*** – [**жу**]*ль* и допустимо [**ж'у**]*ль*, но  [**жу**]*ль Верн*...